# Postgres count isn't running accurate result

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have this Postgres query to return a count from 2 columns by querying from multiple tables.

Here is the example:

```
SELECT
        subscribers.email,
        COUNT(campaign_views.subscriber_id) AS views,
        COUNT(link_clicks.subscriber_id) AS clicks
        FROM campaign_views, link_clicks, subscribers, links
        WHERE campaign_views.campaign_id = 586
        AND link_clicks.campaign_id = 586
        AND link_clicks.link_id = links.id
        AND subscribers.channel = 'email'
        AND subscribers.id = campaign_views.subscriber_id
        AND subscribers.id = link_clicks.subscriber_id
        GROUP BY subscribers.id
```

The issue is that the COUNT result is the same for all of them like this:

```
views | clicks
16  16
6   6
2   2
4   4
```

Any ideas please?

Comment: The result can be explained. (See my answer). However, it is not clear, what your expected result is. If you want us to help you getting a better result: Please show us some data with a minimized (!) example (meaning for example not 4 tables, but only 2).

Comment: @S-Man thanks for the response. The thing is, if I remove every element of link_clicks ... leaving just the views. I get 484 results in total which seems about right. So counting the 2 columns shouldn't be equal for sure

Comment: Once again: You question was: Why is that result, I tried do explain this. If you want us to help you any further, you must present us a minimized example which shows your problem and the expected result.

Comment: The results must be the same, see your WHERE statement:
        AND subscribers.id = campaign_views.subscriber_id
        AND subscribers.id = link_clicks.subscriber_id

Answer (score 0):

With

```
FROM campaign_views, link_clicks, subscribers, links
```

you are creating a `CROSS JOIN`.

Example with table `a`

```
value_a
-------
1
2
3
```

and table `b`

```
value_b
-------
a
b
```

With

```
SELECT
    *
FROM a, b
```

you're generating:

```
value_a | value_b
--------|--------
      1 | a
      1 | b
      2 | a
      2 | b
      3 | a
      3 | b
```

When you'd execute:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(a.value_a),
    COUNT(b.value_b)
FROM a,b
```

you'll receive:

```
count | count
------|------
    6 | 6
```

`COUNT()` returns all columns. In the result of your `CROSS JOIN` you generated `3 * 2 = 6` records for all columns. So, it makes sense, that all results you get are the same.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The thing is, if I remove every element of link_clicks ... leaving just the views. I get 484 results in total which seems about right. So counting the 2 columns shouldn't be equal for sure

Comment: It's not really a cross join. Shina simply uses the old-style implicit joins in the WHERE clause

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to do the count with the accurate result.

```
WITH camps AS (
SELECT
    subscriber_id,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN subscriber_id = null THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS views 
FROM campaign_views
GROUP BY subscriber_id ),

links AS (
SELECT
    subscriber_id,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN subscriber_id = null THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS clicks 
FROM link_clicks
GROUP BY subscriber_id )

SELECT 
    subscribers.email, camps.views, links.clicks FROM camps, links, subscribers

WHERE camps.subscriber_id = links.subscriber_id
AND camps.subscriber_id = subscribers.id
AND links.subscriber_id = subscribers.id
```